# Play video the first time a phonegap application launches?

Tags: android, cordova, mobile-application

I am newbie to phonegap. In a project I am currently working on, I wanted to play a video on the home screen the first time the application launches.
My approach was to use html5 localstorage. I put a specific value for a key. If I can't retrieve expected value for the key "firstLaunch", I play the video and set the value of "firstLaunch".

Here is the piece of code (in the backbone view js file).

```
  var pref = localStorage.getItem("firstLaunch");

                if(pref == null || pref != "0"){
                      $("#player")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
                    localStorage.setItem("firstLaunch", "0");
                } else {
                    $("#player")[0].src += "&autoplay=0";
                }
```

The video is displayed with the following HTML fragment:

```
<div id="introvid" style="width:100%; height: 45%; ">
    <iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%"  
    src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/u1zgFlCw8Aw?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com&autoplay=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

I tried it on an external browser and worked fine i.e. the first time I render the page , it plays the video but not for subsequent renderings. So my question is

1 )what could be the problem?

2) If there is a better approach you recommend . Thank you .

Comment: Are you using a video tag to play the video?

Comment: @SimonMacDonald no I am using an iframe. I edited the question.